# Is it possible to use Node DNS module in Angular Code?

Tags: node.js, angular, dns, nslookup

I have an requrement where I need to do DNS look up from client side code written in Angular. 
Is it possible to use https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html Dns module in Angular ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Node DNS is a server-side module (specific only to NodeJS) and your angular code is on the client-side. A possible solution for this should be to find a client-side library that supports DNS lookup (which I do not think to exist), or use requests.

Send the request from the client-side to the server-side, perform the DNS lookup on the server-side by using the Node DNS module, and send the result back to the client-side.

Hope this helps.